# boundary for x axis for plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bounding-box

I have a problem with my plot, I want to have a boundary at x=4000 and don't know how to do. My current plot is the one below[image]
and here is the code that I have now

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{only axis on top/.style={axis on top=false, after end      axis/.code={
         \pgfplotsset{axis line style=opaque, ticklabel style=opaque, tick style=opaque,
                      grid=none}\pgfplotsdrawaxis}}}
\newcommand{\drawge}{-- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:0,1) \closedcycle}
 \newcommand{\drawle}{-- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle}
\begin{figure}[htpb] 
\centering 
\label{fig:p3:c1} 
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[only axis on top,
    axis line style=very thick, 
    axis x line=bottom, 
    axis y line=left, 
     ymin=0,ymax=10000,xmin=0,xmax=10000, 
      xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$,grid=major, 
     ytick={0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000},
 xtick={0,2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000},
  ] 
    \addplot [draw=none, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-2000:12000]
             {(100000-13*x)/15} \drawge;  %wzór funkcji
    \addplot [draw=none, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-2000:12000]
             {(95000-15*x)/18} \drawge;
    \addplot [draw=none, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=blue!40, domain=-2000:12000]
             {(99000-16*x)/12} \drawle; 
    \addplot[draw=none, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black!40, domain=-2000:12000]
    {(110000-14*x)/17} \drawge;
     \addplot[draw=none, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black!40, domain=-2000:12000]
    {0*x+6000} \drawge;
    \addplot[draw=none, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black!40, domain=4000:4000.1]
    {x} \drawge; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000]  {(100000-13*x)/15}; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {(95000-15*x)/18}; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {(99000-16*x)/12}; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {(110000-14*x)/17} ;
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {0*x+6000} ;
    \addplot[very thick, domain=4000:4000.1] {x} ;

     \end{axis} 


\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Problem 4, Part A} 
\end{figure}
```

I want to have something like this : 
[image]

Comment: BTW, `\label` should go *after* `\caption`, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the line can be added by specifying the start and end coordinates:

```
\addplot[very thick] coordinates {(4000, 0) (4000, 10000)};
```

Also I had to remove `\pgfplotsdrawaxis`, otherwise, the axis would have been drawn twice with slightly shifted components, see the [first version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/304751/1) of this answer.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{
  only axis on top/.style={
    axis on top=false,
    after end axis/.code={
      \pgfplotsset{
        axis line style=opaque,
        ticklabel style=opaque,
        tick style=opaque,
        grid=none,
      }%
      % \pgfplotsdrawaxis
    },
  },
}
\newcommand{\drawge}{%
  -- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:0,1) \closedcycle
}
\newcommand{\drawle}{%
  -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,0) -- (rel axis cs:0,0) \closedcycle
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[only axis on top,
    axis line style=very thick, 
    axis x line=bottom, 
    axis y line=left, 
    ymin=0,
    ymax=10000,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10000, 
    xlabel=$x_1$,
    ylabel=$x_2$,
    grid=major, 
    ytick={0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000},
    xtick={0,2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000},
  ] 
    \addplot [
      draw=none,
      pattern=horizontal lines,
      pattern color=blue!40,
      domain=-2000:12000,
    ] {(100000-13*x)/15} \drawge;  %wzór funkcji
    \addplot [
      draw=none,
      pattern=north west lines,
      pattern color=blue!40,
      domain=-2000:12000,
    ] {(95000-15*x)/18} \drawge;
    \addplot [
      draw=none,
      pattern=horizontal lines,
      pattern color=blue!40,
      domain=-2000:12000,
    ] {(99000-16*x)/12} \drawle; 
    \addplot[
      draw=none,
      pattern=horizontal lines,
      pattern color=black!40,
      domain=-2000:12000,
    ] {(110000-14*x)/17} \drawge;
    \addplot[
      draw=none,
      pattern=horizontal lines,
      pattern color=black!40,
      domain=-2000:12000,
    ] {0*x+6000} \drawge;
    \addplot[
      draw=none,
      pattern=horizontal lines,
      pattern color=black!40,
      domain=4000:4000.1,
    ] {x} \drawge; 
    \addplot[
      very thick,
      domain=-2000:12000,
    ] {(100000-13*x)/15}; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {(95000-15*x)/18}; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {(99000-16*x)/12}; 
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {(110000-14*x)/17};
    \addplot[very thick, domain=-2000:12000] {0*x+6000};
    \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(4000, 0) (4000, 10000)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]